# groupby .sum() takes only one element in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe with two columns:

[image]

I would like to group the numbers by the column `Fee_Code`. I do the following:

```
df.groupby('Fee_Code').sum()
```

However, as output I get for the row Management fees: `137651.03`, or the first value. When I do:

```
df.groupby('Fee_Code').count()
```

I do see that Management fees has `2` observations. So why is then `.sum()` not working?

---

EDITS:

- `df.groupby('Fee_Code').get_group('Management fees')` returns: [image]

Comment: Can you check the output from this `df.groupby('Fee_Code').get_group('Management fees')` ?

Comment: `df.Fee_Code=df.Fee_Code.str.strip(); df.groupby('Fee_Code').sum();df.groupby('Fee_Code').count()`

Comment: @ResidentSleeper it returns the two rows where there is Management fees with the two values 7057 and 137651

Comment: .strip() did not work @Wen-Ben

Comment: `df.groupby('Fee_Code').get_group('Management fees').Value.sum()` still not work?

Comment: No doesnt work still. Same result

Comment: Are you sure Value is a float?  Try df['Value'] = df['Value'].astype(float)

Comment: Also, try `df.groupby('Fee_Code').get_group('Management fees').Value.apply(lambda x: type(x))` if both of them return int or float then I have no idea too.

Comment: Otherwise, can you supply a minimal example DataFrame that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. My column of values was not numeric, so it was just taking the first element.

To make it numeric I did the following:

```
df.loc[:, 'Value'] = pd.to_numeric( df.loc[:, 'Value'], downcast='float', errors='coerce')
```

And then `.groupby(..).sum(..)` worked perfectly fine.